Shift audio for ios in react-native
my dev team has run into a wall in the development of an app we're creating in react native. We're attempting to shift the audio from in-call speaker mode to media speaker mode in ios. We have 2 different streams of audio (1 from a url and the other from an live video) that both need to come out the media speaker. This works on android but ios is giving us a real headache. Is there any solution?
We've exhausted alot of resources and can't seem to find a solution.
